# VB.Net - Add and save new row to database using InsertOnSubmit

Tags: sql, .net, wpf, vb.net

### Nurse Table (contains extra data but not necessary to include)

Fields: ID, Name, Enabled

Example Data: 1 - Test Nurse - True

My problem: The user clicks the add nurse button and a new nurse is added to the list and the ID is automatically determined based upon the last ID in the table; however, this is not working in this particular block although this same functionality works in other portions of the same program.

Code associated with the problem:

### Nurse class

```
Partial Public Class Nurse

Private Sub Nurse_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
    Using database As New MaternityDatabaseDataContext
        Select Case e.PropertyName
            Case "First_Name"
                If Me.First_Name.Trim <> "" Then
                    database.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Nurses SET First_Name = {0} WHERE TableID = {1}", Me.First_Name, Me.TableID)
                End If
            Case "Last_Name"
                If Me.Last_Name.Trim <> "" Then
                    database.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Nurses SET Last_Name = {0} WHERE TableID = {1}", Me.Last_Name, Me.TableID)
                End If
            Case "Display_Name"
                If Me.Display_Name.Trim <> "" Then
                    database.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Nurses SET Display_Name = {0} WHERE TableID = {1}", Me.Display_Name, Me.TableID)
                End If
            Case "Enabled"
                database.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Nurses SET Enabled = {0} WHERE TableID = {1}", Me.Enabled, Me.TableID)
            Case "HomeNumber"
                If Me.HomeNumber.Trim <> "" Then
                    database.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Nurses SET HomeNumber = {0} WHERE TableID = {1}", Me.HomeNumber, Me.TableID)
                End If
            Case "CellNumber"
                If Me.CellNumber.Trim <> "" Then
                    database.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Nurses SET CellNumber = {0} WHERE TableID = {1}", Me.CellNumber, Me.TableID)
                End If
        End Select
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

Code for the Nurse User Control containing the addButton

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class NursesUserControl

Private NurseList As ObservableCollection(Of Nurse)

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    NurseList = New ObservableCollection(Of Nurse)
    NursesDataGrid.ItemsSource = NurseList
End Sub

Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    Dim employee As New Nurse
    employee.Enabled = True
    NurseList.Add(employee)

    'TODO: Change using statement below to use maternity brain.
    Using database As New MaternityDatabaseDataContext
        database.Nurses.InsertOnSubmit(employee)
        database.SubmitChanges()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub DisableButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles DisableButton.Click
    Dim selectedRow As Nurse = TryCast(NursesDataGrid.SelectedValue, Nurse)
    If selectedRow IsNot Nothing Then
        selectedRow.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub EnableButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles EnableButton.Click
    Dim selectedRow As Nurse = TryCast(NursesDataGrid.SelectedValue, Nurse)
    If selectedRow IsNot Nothing Then
        selectedRow.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NursesDataGrid_CellEditEnding(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs) Handles NursesDataGrid.CellEditEnding
    ' Force update on datagrid cell changes instead of just row changes.
    Static isManualInit As Boolean = True
    If e.EditAction = DataGridEditAction.Commit And isManualInit = True Then
        isManualInit = False
        NursesDataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, True)
        isManualInit = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NursesUserControl_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    'TODO: Change using statement below to use maternity brain.
    Using database As New MaternityDatabaseDataContext
        For Each employee As Nurse In database.Nurses.OrderBy(Function(Nurse) (Nurse.Last_Name))
            If employee.Enabled = True Then
                NurseList.Add(employee)
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

My ERROR: Cannot Insert Null Value into Column TableID in Nurse Table.
Why isn't it automatically finding the TableID based on the last entry in the Nurses table? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table design. It sounds like ID is not set as an identity.

If you can, drop the table and recreate it with `ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)`.

If you can't drop it you will have to manually get the next ID in code.

You can get more info on Identity [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx)